# NDK in Android Studio not working for C++ files

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-studio-2.0

In latest Android Studio 2.0 I am trying to run the ndk example, but build is breaking with the following error:

```
/Users/ktulsia/AndroidStudioProjects/example/app/src/main/jni/hello-jni.cpp
Error:(18, 18) string: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileArm64-v8aDebugHello-jniSharedLibraryHello-jniMainCpp'.
> A build operation failed.
  C++ compiler failed while compiling hello-jni.cpp.
See the complete log at: file:///Users/ktulsia/AndroidStudioProjects/example/app/build/tmp/compileArm64-v8aDebugHello-jniSharedLibraryHello-jniMainCpp/output.txt
```

Comment: If you're trying to use exceptions or STL capabilities from the C++ library, they aren't supported by the default NDK compiler toolchain. You may find some help here: http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

Comment: just trying to run simple helloworld example java calling c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i was very new to NDK it took some time to figure out the approach and options.

here are two very nice pages i have found which helped solve almost all the issues. and understand how the latest Android studio works with NDK.

[link 1](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/)
[link 2](http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/)

even though i referred the above pages but I tried the NDK on Android studio 2.0 and it is working fine. so wanted to share the same